# Tex: wrapfig package problem aligning text

Tags: latex, tex

Using the `wrapfig` package with a table inside a section, the table's first row is not aligned with the text that wraps it. This problem is not present when working outside of a section.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{Section}

    \begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        A & B & C & D \\
        E & F & G &  H\\        
        \end{tabular}
    \label{Mytable}\caption{This is my table.}
    \end{wraptable}

\textbf{This bit of text should be aligned with the table's top row.}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

What this gives is:

[image: Text not aligned with wrapped table's first row]

Whereas ideally I'd like to get something like:

[image: Text hypothetically aligned with wrapped table's first row (not a TeX output)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to adjust `\intextsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}




\begin{document}

    \section{Section}

{
\setlength\intextsep{-0.4ex}
    \begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        A & B & C & D \\
        E & F & G &  H\\        
        \end{tabular}
    \label{Mytable}\caption{This is my table.}
    \end{wraptable}

\textbf{This bit of text should be aligned with the table's top row.}
\lipsum[2]

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! How did you chose the .4ex measure if I may?

Comment: @lomper The .4ex is just trial and error by eye. You may need to fine tune the value.